# Put MySql recordset into multidimensional array in vb.net

Tags: mysql, arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array

I'm switching from VBA to VB.net and I need to put data from an SQL query into a multidimensional array but I didn't found a command like ".getrows" that gets all data and put it all into an array.

I've write a code that seems to work (I put data into an array of arrays) but I don't think it's a good code.

Please suggest me how to improve it.

```
Function mQuery(ByVal CnStr$, ByVal SqlStr$) As Object
    Dim mData() As Object
    Using ds As DataSet = MySqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(CnStr, SqlStr)
        ReDim mData(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)
        Dim RCount% = 0
        Dim mDataTmp() As Object
        For Each mRow As DataRowView In ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
            Erase mDataTmp
            mDataTmp = mRow.Row.ItemArray
            mData(RCount) = mDataTmp
            RCount += 1
        Next
    End Using

    Return mData

End Function
```

Comment: the data is already organized in a perfectly good typed container - the DataTable; why do you need to move it to an untyped array?

Comment: @Plutonix I'm not a pro and my code uses data by taking them from an array. So, if I don't put my "query result" into an array I'll need to write all my code again.

Comment: you said `I don't think it's a good code`, maybe writing it again would not be such a bad thing.  Arrays are rarely recommended for .NET in lieu of Typed collections.  At a minimum consider an ArrayList.

Comment: @Plutonix Sorry, but I do not understand what benefits I would get using arraylist. I need data in the exact order in which they are taken, so why use a not ordered item?